# "Cannot define category for undefined class" error in Xcode 11.3, no access to source file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make a category for a class that gets defined in a source file I don't have access to, namely `RunnerViewController`.

The two important files here are `iPad_RunnerAppDelegate.h` and `FilesBrowser.mm`. I do not have access to the header file's corresponding source file.

`iPad_RunnerAppDelegate.h` contains a forward declaration to the RunnerViewController class, and can reference that class with no difficulties.

However, if I try to `#include "iPad_RunnerAppDelegate.h"` in `FilesBrowser.mm` and then try to create a category in the same file, it doesn't recognise the class name.

[image]

Despite this error appearing, I can still use the RunnerViewController class inside `FilesBrowser.mm`, I just can't make categories for it.

What's happening here, and how would I fix it?

Comment: Did my answer help you? Did you find another way? I try to help but you just disappeared ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this same thing but it was a long time ago. The problem is that without some indication of where to apply the category, your code cannot work alone. What you need is info to the compiler to let it know where it's going to insert the category.

In `FilesBrowser.mm`, you will tell it by adding this BEFORE "iPad_RunnerAppDelegate.h":

```
@interface RunnerViewController: UIViewController // or whatever it actually subclasses
@end
```

Now the compiler knows that its going to insert the category against an Objective C class named `RunnerViewController`.

But - you're not completely done. Now you need to insure that the runtime / loader do the class loading and category insertions at the proper time. This is where my knowledge gets a bit fuzzy, so it may not turn out to be a problem at all.

What I believe needs to occur is for the `RunnerViewController` class to get loaded first, then later at some point the category you wrote applied to it (but this may not be necessary). So if `RunnerViewController` is statically linked into your app (using a .a archive), then you're good for sure. But if that class is in a dylib loaded dynamically, and your category is statically linked - well that might be a problem. I just don't know how long Apple waits to try and deal with the categories (which by the way the `-ObjC` link flag is for.

In any case try the code above first and just see what happens. If `RunnerViewController` is dynamically loaded, and you get some hard runtime error, there is a workaround where you would make your category go into a module/framework that is also dynamically linked, but gets linked after `RunnerViewController`.

In the end I believe you have a good chance of making this happen.